# Header for a list generated with sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to set a title  for my list "vizlist", I have created a split Master/Detail zone, then used sap.m.page class to create the list in the master zone as below:

//======= Master zone ===============

```
        this._vizList = new VizList(); 
        var vizListPage = new sap.m.Page("URE", {

            showHeader: true,
            showFooter: false,
            content: this._vizList.getUI(),


         });
```

do I have to create a new js page dedicated just for the header or is there an easy way to do it while instantiating the vizList.

Comment: Can't you just use the list's `setHeaderText` property to set the list title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to set a title for your page or your VizList? 
For your page you can set a title like this.

```
this._vizList = new VizList(); 
var vizListPage = new sap.m.Page("URE", {
  title: "MyTitle",
  showHeader: true,
  showFooter: false,
  content: this._vizList.getUI(),
});
```

I don't know what your VizList is. Does not seem to be a SAPUI5 class.

Comment: that's what I exactly wanted